# JFET Hartley Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

We have designed this circuit and tried in real life and it is working fine with the frequency between 800kHz to 1.25MHz. I just wanted to learn how to prove that this circuit satisfies the Barkhausen Criteria and also I wanted to calculate the frequency on my own but I do not know the inductance value for the transformer. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Calculate or measure the value you don't know.